# How to make an Android app pick up URL's

Tags: android, url, android-webview, android-browser

Hello am I have build a WebView app for my responsive website I will like that when someone clicks a link related to my domain the Android OS should give the user the opportunity to choose to open the url with the app. Like what happens with normal links and browsers. Thanks in advance.

[image: This is sample an example, I would like my app to show up in the list!]

Answer (score 1):

Look into setting up [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) for your app. This will allow users to choose to open your website url with your app, instead of viewing the url in a mobile browser.